# Null Pointer Exception at createCell - apache POI

Tags: java, excel, nullpointerexception, apache-poi

I have the following code:

```
if (verifica == false) {

                            Row add = wbSheet.getRow(Final);
                            Cell nomeR = add.createCell((short) 3); //Null Pointer Exception
                            nomeR.setCellValue(nome);
                            Final++; 
                        }
```

What I can't understand is why i'm getting this error on that line.
Because the only thing that line do is create a cell, that would be filled in the next line.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Probably wbSheet.getRow(Final) returns null.

Comment: But even if I set a number instead of put the variable  "Final", I still get the same error on the same line

Answer (score 0):

In case your .xlsx file contains any of the formatting for the blank cells, the poi reading is not treating it as null, however if you want to print it's value, it will give NullPointerException.

*If you uncomment the print statement, it will throw NullPointerException.

```
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(xlsFile);
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(end);
XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(1);
int RowWithNullValue=0, RowWithoutNullValue=0;
for (int i=0;i<1000;i++){
    if (sheet.getRow(i)==null)
        RowWithNullValue++;
    else{
        RowWithoutNullValue++;
    //  logger.info(sheet.getRow(0).getCell(0));
    }
}
System.out.println(sheet.getLastRowNum());
System.out.println(RowWithNullValue+","+RowWithoutNullValue);
```

You can check [Apache POI docs.](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator) and how they check for nulls when fetching a row.

Answer (score 0):

XSSFRow.CreateCell needs Its XSSFWorkbook as parent. Make sure if your XSSFSheet was created by a XSSFWorkbook instance.
 NPOI source code :

```
public NPOI.SS.UserModel.Cell CreateCell(int column)
{
    return this.CreateCell(column, NPOI.SS.UserModel.CellType.BLANK);
}        
public NPOI.SS.UserModel.Cell CreateCell(int columnIndex, NPOI.SS.UserModel.CellType type)
{
    Cell cell = new HSSFCell(book, sheet, RowNum, (short)columnIndex, type);

    AddCell(cell);
    sheet.Sheet.AddValueRecord(RowNum, ((HSSFCell)cell).CellValueRecord);
    return cell;
}
```

book,sheet are needed for constructor of HSSFCell.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you have created a excel sheet through fileouputstream but you forgot to create row before creating the cell, i hope this will resolve issues of new comers.